# Group multiple HTTp samplers as one transaction, and have constant throughput

Tags: performance, jmeter, test-plan

In my application, I would like to combine a group of HTTP samplers as one transaction, and have a constant throughput on the group.. ie. when I created a thread group with multiple HTTP samplers and defined a constant throughput timer in the group, I am seeing that it is considering each HTTP sampler separately...

***Test Plan***

**ThreadGroup**

----> request 1

-----> request 2

-----> request 3

------> constant Throughoput timer ( 1.0 req per min)

**It executes as :**

-----> request1

*wait 60 secs*

------> request 2

*wait 60 secs...*

----> request 3
...

**what I would like**

-----request 1
----- request 2
------ request 3

*wait 60 secs*

----- request 1
---- request 2
----- request 3

*wait 60 secs*

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve:

You can put the requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) and tick `Generate parent sampler` box:

[image]

Another option is adding [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as the 4th sampler and put the "wait for 60 sec" there

[image]

And finally you can put a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the 1st Sampler:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

use flow control action at the end of the requests

for better understanding difference between timers & flow control action, please go through this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miZGLaAq4UQ&t=301s